# Flutter firebase composite query listeners are not getting fired

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I've defined the following firestore listener:

```
_eventsDataListener = Firestore.instance
        .collection('events')
        .where('group_id', isEqualTo: _userData.groupId)
        .orderBy('time', descending: true)
        .limit(20)
        .snapshots()
        .listen(onEventsData);
```

It works only once (when entering the state), but doesn't work after that.

Some observations:

1. If I remove the **orderBy** or the **where** conditions it works just fine
2. In my Firebase console I can't see any (automatically) created
   indexes
3. I don't get any errors (in the console) saying I should create an
   index
4. Even if I create such a composite index, it still doesn't work

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Well it seems like creating a composite index solves this issue.
Still, I wonder why I didn't get any errors (in the console) saying I should create an index...